# Why is the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Shouldn't it be $y=ax^2+bx+c$? According to Wikipedia, it is $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

I guess that they are both equations, right?

Comment: No. Wikipedia probably meant a polynomial function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @IanMateus: Why isn't $y=ax^2+bx+c$ an equation?

Comment: Context. $y$ is probably shorthand for $y(x)$, and probably $y$ is a polynomial function. Of course, $y$ could be a constant and that would be an equation, but I don't think this is the case.

Comment: You can have a non-constant y that is not a function in an equation though.

Comment: It would be better if you pointed out the Wikipedia page where you saw it, so we can tell from context.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: Note that Wikipedia wrote "quadratic *function* $y=ax^2+bx+c$".

Comment: What I tried to say is that Wikipedia says the quadratic equation is $0=ax^2+bx+c$. My question is why is it not $y=ax^2+bx+c$ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both equations that involve quadratics, but the usual meaning of "quadratic equation" is that it has only one variable, while $y=ax^2+bx+c$ has two variables ($x$ and $y$).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that conventional usage is sloppy, and has been so for a long time. So, it’s perfectly understandable that anyone would be confused.

Let me give an idiosyncratic, stuffy, formalistic answer to your question. As far as I’m concerned, an *equation* is any mathematical statement in which the verb is an equals sign, “$=$”. Thus both “$ax^2+bx+c=0$” and $y=ax^2+bx+c$” are quadratic equations. What is *not* a quadratic equation is ”$ax^2+bx+c$”.

When one speaks of “solving” an equation of any kind, one ordinarily means taking the equation and finding all values of the indeterminate(s) that make the sentence true. In this case, solving $y=ax^2+bx+c$ would mean drawing the graph, I suppose, and this is certainly never what one means by the expression “solving the quadratic equation”. On the other hand, $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is an equation that has only two solutions, and that’s the one where the quadratic formula comes in. Others may disagree violently with my position; but as my grandmother would say, You pays your money and takes your choice.

Answer (score 0):

$$ax^2+bx+c=y\iff ax^2+bx+(c-y)=0\iff ax^2+bx+c'=0$$

Comment: $y$ isn't a constant though, so $c'$ isn't a constant like $c$, right?

Comment: If it isn't, then the equation can no longer be called quadratic, unless *y(x)* is itself a polynomial of degree $\leqslant2$. Unless *y* is independent of *x*, in which case it acts like a parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got $y(x)$ from unless you are referring to $y$. Can we not see that $y$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 2$ from  $ax^2+bx+c=y$? So you're saying $ax^2+bx+c=y$ is not quadratic if $y$ is not constant?

Comment: Well, think about it: $$ax^2+bx+c=y(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C\iff x^3+(A-a)x^2+(B-b)x+(C-c)=0$$ Is this polynomial equation still of degree $2$ ? Or what if we'd write $$ax^2+bx+c=0\iff bx+c=-ax^2\ ?$$ Would this mean that $ax^2$ is a polynomial of degree $1$ ?